# Is it the best practice to put the loadingMessage code in the prepareFromRequest method in (GWTP)

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, gwtp

I want to check the data at the time the page got loaded. I also want to put the loading indicator popup when checking data so that user will know that the page is loading data.

Look at this code:

```
String item="";
@Override
public void prepareFromRequest(PlaceRequest request){
         super.prepareFromRequest(request);
         item=request.getParameter("item", "");
         addToPopupSlot(loadingPresenter);
         GetData action=new GetData(item);
         dispatchAsync.execute(action, getDataCallback);
}
private AsyncCallback<GetDataResult> getDataCallback=new AsyncCallback<GetDataResult>(){
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loadingPresenter.hide();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(GetDataResult result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loadingPresenter.hide();
                    //code to show data here
        }
}
```

OK, this code works fine in IE and in Firefox, but not ok in Chrome. That is:

In Chrome, after refreshing the page, the indicator did not hide though all data was showed correctly. In IE & Firefox the the indicator got hided properly.

I think there something wrong with Chrome somehow they can't call the `loadingPresenter.hide();`

What should I do? I don't think I should remove the `loadingPresenter` cos the `getData` method also was called when user clicking a button, so i need it to indicate the data is loading. But if i uses `loadingPresenter` then i can't run in Chrome.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, just put the callingMethod inside onReset, then it will be fine cos prepareFromRequest was called too early that some how other widget has not been bound yet & that causing the problem. This should work in all browser.

```
String item="";
@Override
public void prepareFromRequest(PlaceRequest request){
         super.prepareFromRequest(request);
         item=request.getParameter("item", "");

}

@Override
public voi onReset{
         super.onReset();
         addToPopupSlot(loadingPresenter);
         GetData action=new GetData(item);
         dispatchAsync.execute(action, getDataCallback);
}
```